# Electron Jquery Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola como dice el el titulo tengo un problema a al usar jquery con electron.
He estado siguiendo este [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiiwaJUS84Q) ya que he aprendido algo de desarrollo web y recientemente descubrí jquery y como en el tuto no lo usa pense usarlo para variar.

la cosa es que en renderer hace una validacion de un input

```js
// DOM Elements
const linksSection = document.querySelector('.links')
const errorMessage = document.querySelector('.error-message')
const newLinkForm = document.querySelector('.new-link-form')
const newLinkURL = document.querySelector('.new-link-url')
const newLinkButton = document.querySelector('.new-link-button')
const clearStorageButton = document.querySelector('.clear-storage')

newLinkURL.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  newLinkButton.disabled = !newLinkURL.validity.valid;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Electron App</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>My Favorite Websites</h1>

  <div class="error-message"></div>

  <section class="add-new-link">
    <form class="new-link-form">
      <input type="url" class="new-link-url" placeholder="URL" size="100" required autofocus>
      <button type="submit" class="new-link-button" disabled>
                Save
            </button>
    </form>
  </section>

  <section class="links"></section>

  <section class="controls">
    <button class="clear-storage">Clear Storage</button>
  </section>
  <!-- Jquery & renderer -->
</body>

</html>
```

entonces intenté hacerlo con jquery

```js
// Mi codigo
const link_section = $(".links");
const error_message = $(".error-message");
const link_form = $(".new-link-form");
const url_txt = $(".new-link-url");
const link_btn = $(".new-link-button");
const clear_storage = $(".clear-storage");

url_txt.keyup(function (e) {
    link_btn.disabled = !url_txt.validity.valid;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Electron App</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>My Favorite Websites</h1>

  <div class="error-message"></div>

  <section class="add-new-link">
    <form class="new-link-form">
      <input type="url" class="new-link-url" placeholder="URL" size="100" required autofocus>
      <button type="submit" class="new-link-button" disabled>
                Save
            </button>
    </form>
  </section>

  <section class="links"></section>

  <section class="controls">
    <button class="clear-storage">Clear Storage</button>
  </section>
  <!-- Jquery & renderer -->
</body>

</html>
```

Y pues alli la falla
¿Por que sale undefinido?
¿Hay alguna diferencia al hacerlo con querySelector?

Intenté cambiar `link_btn.disabled = !url_txt.validity.valid;` por `link_btn.prop("disabled", false) = !url_txt.valid();` pero no funcionó, ¿de que forma se podria hacer con jquery?

Espero puedan ayudarme, ya que estoy aprendiendo y no me gusta quedarme con la duda, sino solo hubiera copiado el codigo tal y como esta en el tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

Después de  travesear en la consola con los `console.log` me di cuenta que cuando uso jquery para seleccionar `$("element")`, así sea un id siempre los guarda en un array, mi solución fue esta

```js
// Mi codigo
const link_section = $(".links");
const error_message = $(".error-message");
const link_form = $(".new-link-form");
const url_txt = $("#new-link-url");
const link_btn = $("#new-link-button");
const clear_storage = $(".clear-storage");

$(url_txt).keyup(function (e) {
    $(link_btn).prop("disabled", !$(url_txt)[0].validity.valid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Electron App</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>My Favorite Websites</h1>

    <div class="error-message"></div>

    <section class="add-new-link">
        <form class="new-link-form">
            <input type="url" id="new-link-url" placeholder="URL" size="100" required autofocus>
            <button type="submit" id="new-link-button" disabled>
                Save
            </button>
        </form>
    </section>

    <section class="links"></section>

    <section class="controls">
        <button class="clear-storage">Clear Storage</button>
    </section>
    <!-- Jquery & renderer -->
</body>

</html>
```

Los volví a poner en un `$(element)` y con `.prop("disabled")` de jquery.

La parte de `!$(url_txt)[0].validity.valid` le añadí el [0] por que es un array, al parecer su `validity.valid` de jquery se hace con una libreria que es jQuery Validation plugin pero ya lo deje así nada mas.